# How to set maximum user-scale in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have an app in react.
I have a problem with scale, whenever users scale using `ctrl+mouse wheel` in the browser everything just gets ruined.
So I think if I get a way to put a limit on maximum scale limit it would be amazing for users(not to see that ruined UI)

So anyone can help how I can do that in react jsx?

Comment: check this : https://sitebulb.com/hints/mobile-friendly/the-viewport-meta-tag-prevents-the-user-from-scaling/

Comment: but how to use this in react??

Comment: in your index.html

Comment: I added this line but no result `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
  user-scalable="no",initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0,
  maximum-scale=1.0" />`